# Syntax highlighting for Arduino (C/C++) code

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

There have already been several discussions on whether Arduino code is C or C++, and sometimes those tags get removed, which also removes the syntax highlighting.

Maybe C++ style highlighting could be added to the `arduino` tag (or `avr-gcc` tag, or maybe even a new `avr-c++` tag)?

Comment: You could force it to use C++ syntax highlighting by putting `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->` above the code block. Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109

Comment: Having some good default behavour doesn't sound bad @KodosJohnson

Comment: @KodosJohnson Indeed, but then the code in the answers still isn't highlighted properly (or that language hint would have to be placed everywhere).

Comment: Maybe this default highlight should be added only for `avr-c` and `avr-c++` because people use other languages to develop for Arduino, not just C/C++. [Johnny-Five](http://johnny-five.io/) looks like a very nice platform to develop JavaScript code and deploy to Arduino.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Agreed, I upvoted. I just thought I would throw that out there in case the OP wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Why wouldn't these questions have a [[tag:c]] or [[tag:c++]] language tag?